# как отсортировать список словарей по name ключу

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка, словари

В интернете, в том числе и на СО нашел несколько ответов, но то ли я долго понимаю простые всем вещи, то ли криво делаю, в общем, ни один из них не подошел.

Имеется список со словарями

```
a = [{'name':'cde', 'id':1}, {'name':'abc', 'id':2}]
```

прохожусь по нему циклом и достаю значения. Вся проблема в том, что в самом словаре нужно `name` сделать в алфавитном порядке, но ни один из способов не помогает(

Зачастую с применением большинства способов с СО я получаю:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Только вот одним более-менее получилось -

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    sorted(a[1]['name'], key=itemgetter(0))
```

Только в ответ я получил

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Что именно вы пытаетесь сделать? Отсортировать список `a` так, чтобы его элементы располагались в порядке значений их атрибута `name`, отсортировать словари так, чтобы их ключи располагались в определённом порядке, отсортировать символы в строке, хранящейся в атрибуте `name`?

Comment: если задача вам кажется сложной, то разбейте её на более мелкие элементарные подзадачи. Не пытайтесь всё сразу освоить. К примеру, сперва твёрдо усвойте почему *"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"* возникает. Независимо от этого можно обсудить какой смысл "сортировка словаря" имеет (или не имеет в Питоне): что на входе, какой желаемый вывод? Наконец "сортировка списка словарей по заданному критерию" эта уже третья задача. Старайтесь одной проблемой на вопрос ограничиваться, если необходимо несколько независимых Stack Overflow вопросов задайте.

Comment: `a.sort(key=lambda d: d['name'])`

Comment: @slippyk спасибо огромное! Помогло

Comment: @jfs спасибо за ответ! Я учту Ваши советы :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сортировка в `Python` производится по умолчанию лексикографически — т.е. в алфавитном порядке и от меньшего значения к большему.

Чтобы сортировать сложные конструкции по своему условию, нужно предоставить функции сортировки необходимые ключи:

```
# исходный массив
a = [{'name':'cde', 'id':1}, {'name':'abc', 'id':2}]
```

Самый простой и понятный способ - написать отдельную функцию, которая бы возвращала ключи для сортировки:

```
def get_name(dictionary):
    return dictionary['name']

a.sort(key=get_name)
```

Того же можно добиться, используя `lambda`-функции:

```
a.sort(key=lambda dictionary: dictionary['name'])
```

Либо функцию `itemgetter` из модуля `operator`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a.sort(key=itemgetter('name'))
```

В итоге получим список словарей, отсортированных по значению ключа `name`:

```
# [{'name': 'abc', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'cde', 'id': 1}]
```

Comment: Странно, но у меня ничего из этого не работает и на все выводит None